# iOS Simulator iOS 11 strange behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

Anyone seeing the simulator like this as attached[image: Simulator screenshot]?

With new Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235), my simulator hangs as shown in picture, and I have to restart it to get it fixed.

Comment: Have you tried Simulator->Reset content & settings?

Comment: Select simulator -> Hardware -> Restart Or Erase All content and Setting